# Different page for every controller in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I write my code at ASP.NET Web API 4.5 and use nuget package Swashbuckle -https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

I have a lot of controllers in my project , and I want that every controller have a special page with description and with the swagger operations

Until now:

- I override the index.html page with `CustomAsset` function:

  `c.CustomAsset("index", typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly, "proj.index.html");`
- Set description in the index.html to controller actions
- Write function of Filter apply and using the object `SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc`  I delete all the controllers instead the one I want to show like this: 
  `swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(path i dont want)`

The question if I can do separate my controllers to different pages ( lets say every controller have his own index.html file)?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem! anyone have a solution?